# Configurable Shipping Options

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, module, shipping-methods

Magento usually offers a number of shipping options which I can choose from. In my case however, there are two shipping options (let's say `standard` and `premium`), but each one of those has sub-options if you will (for example my shop will take the packaging back if you pay an additional few bucks).

I'm thinking of something like the following:

- `[radio]` standard - 59
- `[radio]` premium - 79

  - `[checkbox]` take back the packaging please - 12
  - `[checkbox]` insure my package - 24
  - `[checkbox]` also, please come with two people and bring the product where I want it - 29

How can I add checkboxes to my shipping options for additional services? Is there a module for this / can I write a module for this myself without rewriting half of Magento's code base?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an option like this to the regular shipping methods, but here's a nice tutorial on how to create your own shipping module:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/

Offtopic, but since you are based in Germany: don't you have to take back the packaging for free by law anyway? If so, you could probably drop that option and just have 3 shipping methods at all (standard, premium and delivery incl. assembly)?

If writing a custom module isn't an option you could have a look at the updateShippingAmount observer that allows you to add another fee to the shipping amount.

Comment: I have seen this tutorial, but it doesn't touch on what I'm asking. I know how to add a shipping method using a module. I'm wondering how I would go about adding an option like mine and integrating it with the system because I've got no starting point and I'm kinda lost. Packaging : not that I know. That would be kind of nasty for Amazon to have to take back all their packaging for example. That can't be asked of a shop. Observer: why do you say "if making a module is not an option"? I thought you use observers in a module o.o I'll have a look at that tomorrow

Comment: Well, you need a so called "Verpackungslizenz" (which is like paying for the recycling of the packaging in advance for the customer) or you need to use "vorlizenzierte Verpackungen" (pre-licensed packaging). As far as I know due to this you are not allowed to charge the customer for returning the packaging ... this FAQ (http://www.jochim-schiller.de/site/56/Neue_Verpackungsverordnung.html) is not up to date, but it covers most of the current status of the "Verpackungsverordnung" (the german packaging regulation)

Comment: OK I'll have a look at that, thanks for the hint, I'll report back. Even if I don't need this though, I've got some other sub options, so the question is still relevant to me